# Handling Navigation Items with Tabs and Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navbar, toolbar

I have created a navigation drawer and added a tablayout like this

***activity_main***

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

***app_bar_main***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#fffaf0"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I get the result shown below:
[image]

However, I tried to add fragments to the tabs so that each navigate item opens a screen that has two tabs "First Semester" and "Second Semester" whose contents are held in the fragments xml but its not working.

***MainActivity***

```
    package com.lini.bdevelopers.geomaticshandbook;

//import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar =  findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionPagerAdapter =

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        //setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        DrawerLayout drawer =  findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    // Create adapter for the view  pager
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new FirstSemester(), "First Semester");
        adapter.addFragment(new SecondSemester(), "Second Semester");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private void setupViewPager2(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new FirstSemester2(), "First Semester");
        adapter.addFragment(new SecondSemester2(), "Second Semester");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private void setupViewPager3(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new FirstSemester3(), "First Semester");
        adapter.addFragment(new SecondSemester3(), "Second Semester");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private void setupViewPager4(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new FirstSemeste4r(), "First Semester");
        adapter.addFragment(new SecondSemester4(), "Second Semester");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private void setupViewPager5(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new FirstSemester5(), "First Semester");
        adapter.addFragment(new SecondSemester5(), "Second Semester");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.year1) {
            setupViewPager(viewPager);
        } else if (id == R.id.year2) {
            setupViewPager2(viewPager);
        } else if (id == R.id.year3) {
            setupViewPager3(viewPager);
        } else if (id == R.id.year4) {
            setupViewPager4(viewPager);
        } else if (id == R.id.year5) {
            setupViewPager5(viewPager);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The code above binds the FirstSemester() and SecondSemester() fragments to all the navigation items. This may not be the right way to go about it, so I need suggestions and help, thanks.

**Secondly**
How do I change the AppBar title to the title of the Navigation item selected?

Answer (score 0):

> Secondly How do I change the AppBar title to the title of the
>   Navigation item selected?

In the onNavigationItemSelected() method in your MainActivity class.. you can do something like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.year1) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Year 1");
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
    } else if (id == R.id.year2) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Year 2");
        setupViewPager2(viewPager);
    } else if (id == R.id.year3) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Year 3");
        setupViewPager3(viewPager);
    } else if (id == R.id.year4) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Year 4");
        setupViewPager4(viewPager);
    } else if (id == R.id.year5) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Year 5");
        setupViewPager5(viewPager);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

As for your first question, you are displaying a viewpager (first and second semester) for any item clicked in the navigation drawer so you shouldn't be expecting a normal-looking code. Crude method though but it's not too poor in efficiency.

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!

Comment: Yeah, with respect to the first question, I kinda figured that, its not very good, besides its not inflating the 2,3,4,5 fragments. So do you have any idea of how I could do it better? By the way thanks for the second one, I think that should do it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to first create YearOne fragment and add the semesters to each Year then you first need to add your YearOne, YearTwo etc fragments to the navigation drawer menu.

I created a simple app to illustrate this some days back https://github.com/mbobiosio/TabLayout

You can attach your TabLayout simply like this in YearOneFragment

```
mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentsAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getActivity()));

    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    mTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I will share what i used in my application. You can reuse the single fragment. Have a look at this

**Mainactivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{
private Toolbar toolbar;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setTitle(R.string.app_name); //Toolbar title at start.
}

 @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment;

    if (id == R.id.year1) {
        fragment = new YearFragment(); //Root Fragment then add semester fragment.
        loadFragment(fragment);
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("YEAR","FIRST YEAR"); //Pass year value
        fragment.setArguments(data);
        toolbar.setTitle("FIRST YEAR");
    }
    if (id == R.id.year2) {
        fragment = new YearFragment();//If your view for fragment is different then create new fragment and change here.
        loadFragment(fragment);
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("YEAR","SECOND YEAR"); //Pass year value
        fragment.setArguments(data);
        toolbar.setTitle("SECOND YEAR");
    }
.
.
.
. //Add upto required navigation items.

}

private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    // load fragment
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

**Year Fragment**

```
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

public class YearFragment extends Fragment {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TabLayout mTabLayout;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_year,container,false);

    mTabLayout =  rootview.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager =  rootview.findViewById(R.id.vp_container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    String year = getArguments().getString("YEAR",""); //Here you can get year value change code according to year value.
}

 public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    String[] titles = {"FIRST SEMESTER"," SECOND SEMESTER"};

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        if(position == 0) {
            return FirstSemester.newInstance(year);
        }
        else {
            return SecondSemester.newInstance(year);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 2;
    }
}

}
```

**frag_year.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/textColor" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vp_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sliding_tabs" />
```

**FirstSemester.java**

```
public class FirstSemester extends Fragment {

private static String yearValue = "";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_firstsem,container,false);
    if(yearValue.equals("FIRST YEAR"))
    {
     //Add Code as per your need.
    }
    return rootview;
}

public static FirstSemester newInstance(String Year) {
    FirstSemester fragment = new FirstSemester();
    yearValue = Year;
    return fragment;
}
```

**frag_firstsem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

//Add your views for Semster fragment.

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hope it will helps.! And i create bundle and pass year value which is used only your framents view for all navigation items are same.So you can change values according to year otherwise if your nav item views are different you should create seperate fragments for Years & seperate for semester too..